# How to set default value to state from prefix or input field

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an issue in edit form, I have to display countrycode from api on input field(Prefix).after display i need to get that value and set it to state. I am getting value from input field(Prefix) when ever onchange is done but i need value without onchange.I mean whatever in dropdown i need to get that value. I need to display countrycode whatever i submitted with form. Then, if user need to change countrycode then he will select country. Based on country selection i need to display country code and set that to state. Hope you will understand my question...

Here is my code.....

```
const [countryCode, setcountryCode] = useState([]) // I am setting Api data into this state

const [subscriber, setSubscriber] = useState({  // here I am getting data what ever I sent to backed...
countryCode: "",

)}
                     
                       <Form.Control 
                                className='add_option' 
                                 type='text' 
                                  name='CountryCode'
                                 onChange={handleChange} 
                                   as="select" required  >
                                           
                                            {
                                                countryCode.map((codes, idx) => (
                                                    <option
                                                        key={idx}
                                                        required
                                                        name='CountryCode'
                                                        className='add_opt'
                                                        value={codes.CountryCode}
                                                          defaultValue={codes.CountryCode}
                                                    >
                                                        {codes.countryCode1}

                                                    </option>

                                                ))
                                            }

                                        </Form.Control>
```

Thanks in Advance.....

Answer (score 0):

You have to think the other way around:
Do not *"get the value from input field"*, but instead, store the current value with `useState` and *set* the `Form.Control` value with e.g. `value={ currentCountryCode }`.

See: [controlled-components](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components).

The `onChange` sets the state (e.g. `setCurrentCountryCode()`), and the `Form.Control` takes the value back from the state.

Then, any other event can also set the state (`setCurrentCountryCode()`), any other function can use the current state (`currentCountryCode`).

E.g.:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import Form from 'react-bootstrap/Form';

export const SelectValue = () => {
    const [ currentCountryCode, setCurrentCountryCode ] = useState(''); // <-- store selected value in state
    const [ countryCode, setcountryCode ] = useState([
        { countryCode: 'xx' },
        { countryCode: 'yy' },
        { countryCode: 'zz' },
    ]);

    const handleChange = function( x ){
        setCurrentCountryCode(x.target.value) // <-- set state by selected value
    };

    useEffect(()=>{
        /*
        fetchCurrentCountryCode().then((value)=>{  // <-- maybe fetch the current value, or something
            setCurrentCountryCode( value )         // <-- set state by fetched value
        })
        */
    }, []);

    useEffect(()=>{
        console.log('currentCountryCode:', currentCountryCode); // <-- do what ever you want with most recent value
    }, [ currentCountryCode ]);

    return (<>
        <Form.Control
            type='text'
            onChange={ handleChange }
            as="select"
            value={ currentCountryCode } // <-- set the value from state
        >
            {
                countryCode.map((codes, idx) => (
                    <option
                        key={ idx }
                        value={ codes.countryCode }
                    >
                        { codes.countryCode }
                    </option>
                ))
            }
        </Form.Control>
    </>);
};
```